# How to put elements from a stack into list and deleting elements

Tags: java, list, stack, awt

I have a stack of fractions and I put them into a list in AWT java.  How do I delete previous elements off the list after performing an operation?

Comment: `list.clear();` doesnt work?

Comment: I do no want to clear all the elements just the previous two.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried creating a temporary stack and clearing all elements of list

Comment: Edit your post and add your code to it and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is really vague, but assuming you're using a `List` of some kind (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc) then this should work:

```
list.remove(list.size()-1);
list.remove(list.size()-2);
```